# How do I filter Purchase Order query in QBXML to only return records that are not fully received?

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

When doing a PurchaseOrderQuery in QBXML I am trying to get Quickbooks to only return purchase orders that are not yet processed (i.e. "IsFullyReceived" == false). The response object contains the IsFullyReceived flag, but the query object doesn't seem to have a filter for it??

This means I have to get every single Purchase Order whether or not it's received, then do the filtering logic in my application - which slows down Web Connector transactions.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

> The response object contains the IsFullyReceived flag, but the query object doesn't seem to have a filter for it??

Correct, there is no filter for it.

You can see this in the docs:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

> This means I have to get every single Purchase Order whether or not it's received, then do the filtering logic in my application - which slows down Web Connector transactions.

Yep, probably.

> Any ideas?

Try querying for only Purchase Orders changed or modified (`ModifiedDateRangeFilter`) since the last time you synced.

Or, instead of pulling every single PO, keep track of a list of POs that you think may not have been received yet, and then only query for those specific POs based on `RefNumber`.

Or, watch the `ItemReceipt` and `BillPayment` objects, and use that to implement logic about which POs may have been recently filled, since `BillPayment and`ItemReceipt` objects should get created as the PO is fulfilled/received.

Comment: Thanks Keith! I've actually been using your code examples quite a bit - thanks for that resource! I've worked with a lot of third party API's, but Quickbooks is definitely the most frustrating!